# Android how to simulate HW INFO button on Galaxy Tab 10.1?

Tags: android

There is not any HW button on Tab 10.1.

I d like to show the menu, when the user click on MENU HARDWARE BUTTON. How I can simulate Menu HW button on Tab 10.1?

Leslie

Answer (score 1):

> There is not any HW button on Tab 10.1.

Correct.

> I d like to show the menu, when the user click on MENU HARDWARE BUTTON.

There is no MENU HARDWARE BUTTON on Honeycomb tablets.

> How I can simulate Menu HW button on Tab 10.1?

You cannot "simulate" hardware. You are welcome to have your activity detect the volume control buttons and take actions based upon those. Note that there is no guarantee that every Android device going forward will have hardware volume control buttons, either -- in fact, it would not surprise me in the least if tablets start dropping those.